# Android Things microphone support

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

Does Android Things on the  raspberry pi 3 support a usb microphone already? 
If not I could attach a microphone to the RPi3 via an ADC (and talk to it via SPI) but can I get Android to see it as a microphone by registering it as a user driver? - I need to record it with MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 3):

As [@devunwired](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246461/devunwired) commented in the [Google's IoT Developers Community](https://plus.google.com/112090467711235891544/posts/78pNQa52Li2): USB accessory support is not currently enabled is the RC1 preview.

While it is possible to talk to an ADC over SPI using the [`SpiDevice`](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/spi.html) class, sampling at 44.1khz sounds very challenging with the `preview-RC1` implementation of the [Peripheral I/O API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/index.html) that doesn't currently expose APIs for DMA/I2S controllers.

Additionally the `preview-RC1` implementations of the [User-space Driver API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/index.html) currently only support those 3 framework peripheral types:

- HID
- Sensors
- GPS

I would suggest filing feature requests on b.android.com using [this template](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Things%20feature%20request) for all those!

Comment: I'm currently asking myself the same question. Has there been any update on this? @seb could you please provide a link to the issue you created?

Comment: @DeveloBär the issue is here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230434&q=microphone&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: It looks like this is now supported according to the issue linked in the previous comment and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37130239). Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

After [DP2 release](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#developer_preview_2) Anddroid Things now supports USB audio
You can use USB microphone or USB speaker